# Primefaces tree - selection not updated in <p:layout /> with <ui:include/>

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm experimenting using a navigation tree with a `<p:layout />` and an `<ui:include />`, which I want to dynamically update the `<ui:include />` when I click on a tree node.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui">
<f:view contentType="text/html">
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
<p:layout fullPage="true">
   <p:layoutUnit position="left" width="200" resizable="true" collapsible="true">
      <h:form>
         <p:tree expanded="true" nodeSelectListener="#{menutree.onTreeNodeClicked}" id="tree"
               value="#{menutree.menuTree}" var="node" update="test,tree"
               selection="#{menutree.selectedNode}" selectionMode="single">
            <p:treeNode>
               <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
            </p:treeNode>
         </p:tree>
      </h:form>
   </p:layoutUnit>
       <p:layoutUnit position="center" resizable="true" collapsible="false">
      <h:panelGroup id="test" layout="block">
         <ui:include src="${menutree.selectedNode.name}.xhtml" />
      </h:panelGroup>
   </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
</h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

The backing bean looks like this:

```
@SessionScoped
public class MenuTreeBean implements Serializable
{
    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    private final TreeNode root;

    private TreeNode selectedNode;

    public MenuTreeBean()
    {
        root = new DefaultTreeNode("root", null);

        CustomTreeNode aaRoot = new CustomTreeNode("welcome", "Widgets", root);

        new CustomTreeNode("1", "Editor", aaRoot);
        new CustomTreeNode("2", "Calendar", aaRoot);

        setSelectedNode(aaRoot);
    }

    public TreeNode getMenuTree()
    {
        return root;
    }

    public TreeNode getSelectedNode()
    {
        logger.info("Selected: " + selectedNode);
        return selectedNode;
    }

    public void setSelectedNode(TreeNode selectedNode)
    {
        logger.info("Selected: " + selectedNode);
        this.selectedNode = selectedNode;
    }

    public void onTreeNodeClicked(NodeSelectEvent e)
    {
        logger.info("Clicked: " + e.getTreeNode());
        selectedNode = e.getTreeNode();
    }
}
```

Correspondingly, there are few more little pages, which contain nothing more than a Primefaces widget - or simply HTML.

This gives such layout in the web browser:

```
------------------------------------
| Widget      |                    |
|   Editor    |                    |
|   Calendar  |                    |
|             |                    |
|             |                    |
|             |                    |
|             |                    |
|             |                    |
|             |                    |
------------------------------------
```

The problem I have is

- when I click on the Editor node above, it gets selected and highlighted, and the `<ui:include />` loads the page/chunk I requested
- when I click on the Calendar node above, it gets selected and highlighted, and the `<ui:include />` loads the page/chunk I requested
- when I click back on the Editor node above, it did not get selected, but the `<ui:include />` still loads the page/chunk I requested; the Calendar node was still highlighted

If I turn off the update attribute at `<p:tree />`, tree node selection and highlight is working as expected; except I miss the dynamic `<ui:include />` which I needed.

As for the logging traces above, Widgets is set to be selected initially. Then, when I clicked Editor, the sequence of the methods are

```
2011/05/24 23:06:25 com.foo.bar.MenuTreeBean getSelectedNode
INFO: Selected: Widgets
2011/05/24 23:06:25 com.foo.bar.MenuTreeBean getSelectedNode
INFO: Selected: Widgets
2011/05/24 23:06:25 com.foo.bar.MenuTreeBean setSelectedNode
INFO: Selected: Editor
2011/05/24 23:06:25 com.foo.bar.MenuTreeBean onTreeNodeClicked
INFO: Clicked: Editor
2011/05/24 23:06:25 com.foo.bar.MenuTreeBean getSelectedNode
INFO: Selected: Editor
```

But when I clicked Calendar, the sequence became

```
2011/05/24 23:07:15 com.foo.bar.MenuTreeBean getSelectedNode
INFO: Selected: Editor
2011/05/24 23:07:15 com.foo.bar.MenuTreeBean getSelectedNode
INFO: Selected: Editor
2011/05/24 23:07:15 com.foo.bar.MenuTreeBean setSelectedNode
INFO: Selected: Editor
2011/05/24 23:07:15 com.foo.bar.MenuTreeBean onTreeNodeClicked
INFO: Clicked: Calendar
2011/05/24 23:07:15 com.foo.bar.MenuTreeBean getSelectedNode
INFO: Selected: Calendar
```

I wonder if I miss anything out so that when I click the tree nodes, the `<ui:include />` will load, and the tree node gets highlighted?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can understand what you are trying to do but I don't necessarily think this is the best approach.

Rather than dynamically changing the `src` attribute of a `<ui:include` tag you should look into a master template page that all child pages will inherit their base content from.

In your template page you can define a layoutUnit as such:

```
<p:layoutUnit position="center" scrollable="true">
  <ui:insert name="content">
  <!-- content would go here -->
  </ui:insert>
</p:layoutUnit>
```

Then in your child pages you would specify a composition tag.

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/master.xhtml">
```

Now your tree nodes rather than dynamically update a src attribute can just redirect to the appropriate URL and your tree node and master page content will load appropriately.

Comment: Seems more a workaround rather than solution, as this would mean refreshing the browser instead of doing a PPR. But thanks for the insight anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with maple_shaft that you should be using a template for this.   However if you must stick with this look at the **update** attribute of the **p:tree** element.   There you specify an ID of an element to update, which can be your **ui:include** element since that is a UIComponent.

In my application I am also using a **p:tree** for navigation, but I prefer to force a redirect when a node is clicked.  The reason for this that the resulting page is book-markable by the browser.  In other words the target URL ends up in the browser address text box.

The way I do this is in the backing bean as follows:

```
public void onNodeSelect(NodeSelectEvent event) {

    selectedNode = event.getTreeNode();
    String url =  // compute some URL to move to based on selectedNode

    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
    try {
        ec.redirect(url);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Navigation.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

To reiterate:  Use a template even if that means a learning curve for you and it will actually force your webapp to be more cohesive and disciplined.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I solved the problem on my own.

It turned out to be some problem in the Javascript, that the tree node won't get highlighted when I specify `<p:tree update="" />` to more than one destinations.

So after reading the code and YUI docs, finally I workaround the problem by adding a Javascript function to the onNodeClick handler of `<p:tree />`, to force highlighting the selected node.

The function just forces highlighting the clicked node.

```
function highlightNode(e)
{
    e.node.highlight();
}
```

At least works for my situation with using official Primefaces jars :)